# Java println method from another class

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm having a bit of a problem with a method from another class

The method i want to is:

```
/**
 * Prints out information about the owner
 */
public void printOwnerInfo()
{
    System.out.println("Information about the owner of the forest");
    System.out.println("Name: " + name);
    System.out.println("Adresse: " + adresse);
    System.out.println("Phone Number: " + phone);
}
```

I would like to have this information printed along side:

```
/**
 * Prints out information about the forest
 */
public void printForestInfo()
{
    System.out.println("Information about forest: " + name);
    System.out.println("Location: " + location);
    System.out.println("Square meters: " + squareMeters);
    System.out.println("Price per square meter: " + price + " euro");
    System.out.println("Price for the forest: " + (squareMeters * price) + " euro");
    System.out.println.forestOwner.printOwnerInfo();
}
```

I've declared the "Owner" class in the "Forest" field as:

```
public Owner forestOwner;
```

But I can't seem to get it to print out the Owner information with the Forest information.
they work fine each on there own.

Comment: Change `System.out.println.forestOwner.printOwnerInfo();` to `forestOwner.printOwnerInfo();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call doesn't make sense:

```
System.out.println.forestOwner.printOwnerInfo();
```

This would only start to be sensible if `printOwnerInfo()` returned a `String` (which you're then passing into your `System.out.println` call), and if you corrected the chain of calls. So, either replace that line with this:

```
forestOwner.printOwnerInfo()
```

... or have that owner method return a `String` instead and call it like so:

```
System.out.println(forestOwner.printOwnerInfo());
```

Answer (score 0):

This makes no sense

```
System.out.println.forestOwner.printOwnerInfo();
```

I guess you want to print from the object `forestOwner` the method `printOwnerInfo()` so:-

```
forestOwner.printOwnerInfo();
```

Which will call the method on the object and the `Println`s are handled in there

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do something like the following in the printForestInfo method:

```
forestOwner.printOwnerInfo();
```

... as your code prints to the console from within that method. The 'out' field of the System class is declared static and public, thus it is "available" globally.